# Why does the ben chocham ask "you"?

Tags: passover-seder-hagada

In one version of the hagadah the ben chocham asks "what are these adus, chukim and mishpatim, that Hashem commanded you"? (Another version says "us")

Why does the ben chocham ask "you"? Isn't that what the ben opposite-of-chochom also asks, yet it says that ok that case he took himself out of the general category of everyone else, so then why would the ben chocham also say it, and why is it not considered taking himself out of the category of everyone else?

Comment: @joel oh nice I didn't see that before